# Fleck WebSockets behaviour

Tags: websocket

SignalR documentation says:

```
SignalR uses the new WebSocket transport where available, and falls back to older transports where necessary
```

Does Fleck have something like this or it uses always own implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Fleck is just a Websocket component. You can use XSocket.net, it has long polling fallback.

Comment: It seems you mean XSockets.net. It is not free. Are there any free alternatives?

Comment: What the hell, it was free before although not opensource. With long polling fallback it is the only one that comes to my mind. However, why do you need such thing anyway? WebSockets are well supported.